# Node js setInterval For Two Players

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am developing a game in node.js and socket.io and jquery.At the main time two users logging to the site with different location and different browser. When the first user is login to play game then a message should come "Your Turn " and he will play 30 sec. in his turn. After 30 sec. the turn goes to second user who is logged in with different location "Your turn " after the completion of 30 sec. of second user the turn goes to first user and this process will continue .

This is my app.js in node.js

```
 var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , http = require('http')
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(8080);
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
   var users = {};

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('addUser', function(user){
    socket.user = user;
    users[user] = user;
    socket.emit('updateUser',
    socket.user + ' has connected to this game');
    });
    socket.on('playGame1', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('update',  data);
    });
    });
```

And this is my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Development In Node.js</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        //var left = {'left': '-=100'};
        socket.on('connect', function(){    
            socket.emit('addUser', prompt('Please Enter your username'));
        });

        socket.on('update',function (data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#arrow').css('left',data.left);
            $('#arrow').css('top',data.top);
            if(data.top == 50){
                alert("you won");
            }
        });

        socket.on('updateUser', function(user){         
            $('#displayUser').append('<b>'+ user +'</b>');  
        });

    //  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
                    //          $('#loadPage').load( alert('Your Turn') );
                    //      }, 20000);


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    if(e.which == 37){
                        $('#arrow').css({'left': '-=100'});
                    }
                    if(e.which == 38){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'top': '-=100' });
                    }
                    if(e.which == 39){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'left': '+=100' });
                    }
                    if(e.which == 40){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'top': '+=100' });                        
                    }
                    //e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)

                    var data = {left:$('#arrow').position().left,top:$('#arrow').position().top};
                                socket.emit('playGame1', data);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #arrowContainer{
                height: 500px;
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #arrow{
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 250px;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            #displayUser{
                float: none;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 500px;
                height: auto;
            }
            #result{
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="loadPage">
        <div id="displayUser"></div>
        <div id="arrowContainer">
            <div id="result">+</div>
            <div id="arrow">*</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So please tell me how to do that setInterval for two players. here is my code.When i am creating that then the call goes at the same time to the both users but i dont want that.Its a full running code you can check it.

Thanks Raghvendra

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider from your description. These are just ideas as your build the app - the code to run it would be much more.

Consider a web socket "channel" for each client (and at least for each game). Perhaps a [room or namespace](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) from the socket.io docs. This would allow you to send a message to just the right client. Alternatively, you could filter on the client side with some identifier e.g. "This message is for id=player1". They both get the message, and your client code shows it when it matters.

`setInterval` will be defined on the server side. Likely this will need to be perGame, and you would cancel the internal when the game ends. You could do it globally on the server as well (just consider the processing when the internal runs, if you have many games...). For this simple example, use Node's native call [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg)

```
function changeTurns(){
   //check server for message to send.
   //check server for web socket to send message to
   //send message
}

setInterval( function(){
  changeTurns();
}, 30000 );
```

The server should also track whos turn it is. Maybe the client will disable actions when its not their turn, but better would be to not allow actions when it is not their turn from the server. You will likely need to send a message to both clients, so the one knows their turn is over, and the other knows their turn has begun. This could be a single message with a parameter checked on the client side, or two different messages `turnOver` and `turnStarted` sent to their respective clients.